# How do I define a Rust struct with a WebAssembly constructor?

Tags: rust, webassembly

I'm trying to export a struct from Rust to WebAssembly, but I'm getting the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: wasm.Test is not a constructor

Rust:

```rust
use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;

#[wasm_bindgen]
extern "C" {
    #[wasm_bindgen(js_namespace = console)]
    fn log(s: &str);
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub struct Test {
    pub x: i32,
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
impl Test {
    #[wasm_bindgen(constructor)]
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            x: 0,
        }
    }
}
```

JS:

```js
import init from './wasm.js'

async function run() {
    const wasm = await init().catch(console.error);
    console.log(wasm);

    let test = new wasm.Test();

    console.log(test);
}

run();
```

What would be the correct way to export a struct?

Comment: Not answering the question, but for anyone wondering about the obvious, here's [the wasm-bindgen reference on exporting with a constructor](https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/wasm-bindgen/reference/attributes/on-rust-exports/constructor.html) which matches the code in this question — except for the intermediate `wasm.js` module. Could you show what's in your `./wasm.js` module, just in case?

Comment: It worked when a imported the class `Test`. In the `wasm` variable I just have access to some functions. I'm not sure the reason of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `init()` when resolved, returns the WASM module's exports. So you won't find `Test`, instead you'd find `test_new` representing `Test::new`. This should be visible in the console after executing `console.log(wasm);`.

To resolve your issue, you instead need to import `Test`, where you initially import `init`.

```js
import init, { Test } from './wasm.js';

async function run() {
    const wasm = await init().catch(console.error);
    console.log(wasm);

    let test = new Test();
    console.log(test);
}

run();
```